# Firebase read permissions denied even with open security rules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm getting the rather common `Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.` error. Usually this is because you haven't changed your security rules, i.e. they're too strict. In my case, though, I've tried a few different rule sets, with increasing liberalism:

This is my original rule, and I can see why *maybe* that would only work if you're logged in:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow update: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

The `read` rules then became (everything else stayed the same):

`allow read: if true;`

then became:

`allow read;`

Each time, I still got the same error.

For reference, here's how I'm making the call:

App.js

```
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); // copied from SDK snippet

// then, inside the component:
useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setLoggedIn(true);
      }
    });
    getTeas(app);
  });
```

firebase.js

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";

export function getTeas(app) {
  const db = firebase.firestore(app);
  db.collection("teas")
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Instead of showing multiple rules fragments of what you tried, can you edit your question to show a single, *complete* ruleset that you think should work with your code, but doesn't?

Comment: Updated my question with a complete rule set!

Comment: The rules grant access to a collection `/users`, but your code is trying to read from `/teas` to which you grant no access for anyone.

Comment: ahhh, I see. So If I add a separate rule for `match/teas { // rule in here}` I should be able to perform a `get()`? Also, Do you know what would be the most secure way to allow those calls without making it totally open? No need to restrict to specific users, but do want to ensure the calls can only come from my app and not anywhere.

Comment: Fir *this* question I really recommend reading https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure, as that covers the structure of the security rules. For you second question, there is currently no way to restrict access to just your app. I recommend doing some searches for that though, as it's been covered in some detail before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rules grant access the `/users` collection. No matter what condition you specify (the part after `if`) it will only apply to access to the `users` collection.

Your code is trying to read from the `/teas` collection. Since no rule is declared that grants access to `/teas`, the operation is rejected.

If you *also* want to grant access to `/teas` you'll need to add an additional rule for that, as shown in the Firebase documentation on [structuring Firestore security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure).